# High Sierra: Can't merge BOOTCAMP partition with APFS container

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, high-sierra, apfs

I feel like this is a known problem on High Sierra, but I can't delete my BOOTCAMP partition to gain "Free Space" and I also can't expand my APFS container that contains my MACINTOSH HD. It's like they've turned into seperate hard disks, and I can't move over the space from the old file system to the new one.
This is what I find when I type diskutil list into terminal:

[image: diskutil]

I tried manually deleting the BOOTCAMP partition using terminal, and then expanding the container: I tried using the diskutil apfs resizeContainer. But I got an error saying that the target disk has no space (i.e. it doesn't detect the free space).
Any solutions?

Comment: What did you do to make your BootCamp partition Apple_HFS style (it should be Microsoft Basic Data)?

Comment: I pressed erase in disk utility and made it into Apple_HFS style.

Answer (score 1):

First convert the former Boot Camp partition to free space:

```
sudo diskutil eraseVolume "Free Space" %noformat% /dev/disk0s3
```

Then expand your APFS container to the max (0 is a magic size here):

```
diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 0
```

Comment: I actually tried this method, but before Dev Beta 7, the APFS container couldn't detect the empty space. In Beta 7 you can just use disk utility to fill the empty space. Not sure if above method will work.