# How to reclaim space after removing bootcamp

Tags: macos, hard-drive, bootcamp, partition

I removed my bootcamp through "Boot Camp Assistant". Some how the 200 GB allocated for bootcamp didnt merged into Standard Macintosh HD drive. so i went for online solution and found following article on web page that looked professional.

[How to reclaim your APFS space after removing bootcamp](https://medium.com/@legolasWang/how-to-reclaim-your-apfs-space-after-removing-bootcamp-b077887b9637)
so i followed the advise and ran following commands in terminal :

`diskutil list`

`sudo diskutil eraseVolume free none disk0s3` disk0s3 was the unpartitioned space of 200GB from bootcamp. Then I was supposed to run the following command:

`sudo diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s1 0` but it returned some error.

Now even the disk0s3 of 200 GB doesn't get listed and i am left with only 300GB space for Macintosh HD drive.I have posted the latest screenshot of "diskutil list" command.
[image]

As you can see GUID_partition_scheme still has 500 GB size(with an *) but i am unable to access the 200 GB out of it. I have tried even resetting the mac i.e deleting and erasing the Mainctosh HD and reinstalling MacOS Catalina but still i got only 300 GB.Any help in this regard would be much appreciated.

EDIT: Problem solved. apparently someone else had exactly same issue and had their problem solved here: [Missing HDD space after running diskutil commands](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/317608/missing-hdd-space-after-running-diskutil-commands)
the solution provided(which worked out too) was same as i followed from article. It turns out that I also needed to run the "sudo diskutil eraseVolume free none disk0s2" command before executing "sudo diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s1 0".

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :) Can I suggest it may be worth adding a link to the article you followed? Also, have you searched this site for answers? I'm pretty sure we have many similar situations covered here. Does https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/235987/deleted-bootcamp-partition-and-it-just-disappeared-nothing-to-merge-with-osx-pa?rq=1 or https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/295910/high-sierra-cant-merge-bootcamp-partition-with-apfs-container?rq=1 or https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/356658/lost-space-after-removing-bootcamp?rq=1 help at all?

Comment: @Monomeeth Hi, The article i followed was
https://medium.com/@legolasWang/how-to-reclaim-your-apfs-space-after-removing-bootcamp-b077887b9637

Comment: A big thanks to you @monomeeth for guiding me in the right direction